# Prevent a decrease the size of image less than 100% during zooming

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

My UIImageView contains inside UIScrollView.

```
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
```

When I try to reduce my image, the size of image becomes equal to 50%.
When I removed fingers, size of image becomes equal to 100% again.

How can I prevent a decrease the size of less than 100% during zooming?

[image: zoom out UIImageView]

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
    scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0        
    centerScrollViewContents()
}

func centerScrollViewContents() {
    let boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    var contentsFrame = imgView.frame

    if contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0
    }

    if contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0
    }

    imgView.frame = contentsFrame
}
```

Comment: show screenshots ?

Comment: I just added screenshots

Comment: show some code what you are doing with that image  ..

Comment: I added my code